# How to mix php and C++ for user authenication?

Tags: php, c++

Hello i'm making a program to get the names of users on my website and use that log for my programs so only registered people can login. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please clarify the question, what exactly would you want to do with C++? If it's accessing the user credentials, then you could probably use the MySQL C API (assuming that you're using MySQL to store these, which is very likely).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're paying too much attention to the choice of tools you're going to use, before you know what you're going to do. What I would suggest is:

1. Decide **what** you want to do. If you're going to authenticate logins against a user list of some sort, state exactly what you want to do.
2. Once you know what you want to do, decide **how** you are going to do it. Have a look at other solutions, such as HTTP Basic authentication, or using cookies, or some other method, and decide which method is best for your needs.
3. Once you have a thorough understanding of how you want to implement your solution, you can decide on which **tools** you would like to use. Again, evaluation of other existing solutions will help you in this decision.
4. **Implement** your solution, following your plan in (2).

Comment: I agree with you and Wim.  The OP doesn't seem to have a handle on exactly what they want to do /or/ how they want to do it.  Some obvious questions are, "Where is the user list?", and "What are the roles of the planned C++ tool and the PHP code?"